# Networkx - How to find the average shortest path length of weakly connected component in case of a directed graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to find the average shortest path length of weakly connected components but the version 3.1 of networkx throws an error that the graph is not strongly connected.

```
wcc_subs = (G.subgraph(c) for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G))
G_wc = max(wcc_subs, key=len) #the largest weakly connected subgraph
shortest_wc=nx.average_shortest_path_length(G_wc)
shortest_wc
```

This is the code that I have tried.

Comment: As you can check in the docs, starting from version 3.0 an exception is raised for directed graphs that are not strongly connected. So you can install an older version of networkx. Source: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.average_shortest_path_length.html

Comment: Please update your question with the formula of how you would like to compute the average shortest path in case the graph is not strongly connected